# Firebase+ReactJS: 'importScripts' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Firebase-message-sw.js:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

// BG-4OSXtyPghJusRY97ROcRWcTnaa9gWGm1jIHRyfLdfiXhzoItl5QfkLxUbj9MytqwobDAUneyRm9FYq3xWuuc

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Retrieve firebase messaging
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('Received background message ', payload);

  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

I am getting the following error: 'importScripts' is not defined.
I am trying to get the token, but one more error is happening in this line:
`getToken({messaging ,vapidKey: messageKey})`
The error is:
`The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').`

Answer (score 1):

**Better replace with this code, worked for me**

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js");
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-messaging.js");
// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing the generated config
const firebaseConfig = {
// your firebaseConfig
};

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Retrieve firebase messaging
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log("Received background message ", payload);
  // dataHandler();
  // const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  // const notificationOptions = {
  //   body: payload.notification.body,
  //   // icon: "./logo192.png",
  // };

  // // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
  // return self.registration.showNotification(
  //   notificationTitle,
  //   notificationOptions
  // );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try directly importing the firebase packages

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "*******************************",
authDomain: "********************",
projectId: "***************",
storageBucket: "**********",
messagingSenderId: "********",
appId: "**********************"
};

const fire = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default fire;
```